# Out-Of-Browser Silverlight application doesn't display ClientBin content

Tags: silverlight

I use some images in ClientBin folder in my Silverlight 5 application. Everything is OK when I run it in browser, but when I change application to out of browser, images in program ClientBin are not displayed (I read them using `new BitmapImage(new Uri(".....", UriKind.Relative))`)

what is going wrong here? Should I place ClientBin folder next to my Out of Browser app? where is my OOB app? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any chance you're running out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an absolute Uri with a fully qualified url to your images.  When Silverlight is running OOB, it's not running in the context of the web site hosting the xap file, so it has no idea of what the relative path is.

Comment: How can I make an absolute path? should I know path of my out of browser app?